# AChartEngine-Combined TimeChart and ScatterChart, X-Axis date

Tags: android, achartengine

I have created a graph where tamperatures are displayed in a timeChart. I needed to mark a few temperatures with different color, so I used a XYCombinedChart and added a ScatterChar with the temperatures I wanted to mark. It all worked well. The only problem is that, in order to make it work, I  used milliseconds in ScatterCharts's XYSeries like shown below:

```
XYSeries pointSeries = new XYSeries("NotFromSensor");    
dataset.addSeries(pointSeries);    
int t = 0;    
for (t = 0; t < MainActivity.temps.size(); t++){    
    pointSeries.add(dt[t].getTime(), MainActivity.temps.get(t));    
}
```

The whole code of creating the graph is shown below:

```
public class DeviceGraphActivity extends Activity {
private XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset, pointDataset ;
private XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer;
private XYSeriesRenderer renderer1, pointRenderer;

public GraphicalView getDeviceView(Context context, String title){
    dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
    clearDataset();// a set with all the data that will be displayed on the graph
    mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();//determines the variables of the overall graph        
    int i;
    System.out.println(ShowGraphActivity.flag);
    if(DeviceFilterActivity.checkedDevices.isEmpty()){
        if(ShowGraphActivity.flag == true){

            MainActivity.setXYValues("SELECT Temperature, Time FROM Temperatures WHERE Time BETWEEN " +
                    "'"+(MainActivity.yy1)+"-"+((MainActivity.mm1))+"-"+(MainActivity.dd1)+"' " +
                            "AND '"+(MainActivity.yy2)+"-"+((MainActivity.mm2))+"-"+((MainActivity.dd2))+"'");
            setData(false);
            MainActivity.setXYValues("SELECT Temperature, Time FROM Temperatures WHERE FromSensor = 0 AND Time BETWEEN " +
                    "'"+(MainActivity.yy1)+"-"+((MainActivity.mm1))+"-"+(MainActivity.dd1)+"' " +
                            "AND '"+(MainActivity.yy2)+"-"+((MainActivity.mm2))+"-"+((MainActivity.dd2))+"'");
            setData(true);

        }
        else{
            MainActivity.setXYValues("SELECT Temperature, Time FROM Temperatures");
            setData(false);
            MainActivity.setXYValues("SELECT Temperature, Time FROM Temperatures WHERE FromSensor = 0");
            setData(true);
        }
        renderer1 = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        renderer1.setLineWidth(3);//sets graph line's width
        renderer1.setChartValuesTextSize(20);//sets the size of the text on the char
        renderer1.setColor(Color.BLUE);//sets the color of the graph
        renderer1.setDisplayBoundingPoints(true);
        mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer1);//adds the renderer(1 graph) to the overall graph

        pointRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        pointRenderer.setLineWidth(3);//sets graph line's width
        pointRenderer.setChartValuesTextSize(20);//sets the size of the text on the char
        pointRenderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
        pointRenderer.setColor(Color.RED);//sets the color of the graph
        pointRenderer.setDisplayBoundingPoints(true);
        mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(pointRenderer);
    }
    else{
        for(i = 0; i < DeviceFilterActivity.checkedDevices.size(); i++){
            if(ShowGraphActivity.flag){
                MainActivity.setXYValues("SELECT Temperature, Time FROM Temperatures WHERE DeviceID = "+DeviceFilterActivity.checkedDevices.get(i).getId()+" AND Time BETWEEN " +
                    "'"+(MainActivity.yy1)+"-"+((MainActivity.mm1))+"-"+(MainActivity.dd1)+"' " +
                            "AND '"+(MainActivity.yy2)+"-"+((MainActivity.mm2))+"-"+((MainActivity.dd2))+"'");
                setData(i, false);
                MainActivity.setXYValues("SELECT Temperature, Time FROM Temperatures WHERE FromSensor = 0 AND DeviceID = "+DeviceFilterActivity.checkedDevices.get(i).getId()+" AND Time BETWEEN " +
                        "'"+(MainActivity.yy1)+"-"+((MainActivity.mm1))+"-"+(MainActivity.dd1)+"' " +
                                "AND '"+(MainActivity.yy2)+"-"+((MainActivity.mm2))+"-"+((MainActivity.dd2))+"'");
                setData(i,true);
            }
            else{
                MainActivity.setXYValues("SELECT Temperature, Time FROM Temperatures WHERE DeviceID = "+DeviceFilterActivity.checkedDevices.get(i).getId());
                setData(i, false);
                MainActivity.setXYValues("SELECT Temperature, Time FROM Temperatures WHERE FromSensor = 0 AND DeviceID = "+DeviceFilterActivity.checkedDevices.get(i).getId());
                setData(i, true);
            }
            renderer1 = new XYSeriesRenderer();
            renderer1.setLineWidth(3);//sets graph line's width
            renderer1.setChartValuesTextSize(20);//sets the size of the text on the chart
            renderer1.setColor(DeviceFilterActivity.checkedColors.get(i));//sets the color of the graph
            renderer1.setDisplayBoundingPoints(true);
            mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer1);//adds the renderer(1 graph) to the overall graph 

            pointRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
            pointRenderer.setLineWidth(3);//sets graph line's width
            pointRenderer.setChartValuesTextSize(20);//sets the size of the text on the chart
            pointRenderer.setColor(Color.RED);//sets the color of the graph
            pointRenderer.setDisplayBoundingPoints(true);
            mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(pointRenderer);
        }
    }


    mRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(20);
    mRenderer.setPanEnabled(true);
    mRenderer.setZoomEnabled(true);
    mRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);
    mRenderer.setYAxisMax(50);
    mRenderer.setYAxisMin(0);
    mRenderer.setShowGrid(true);
    mRenderer.setMargins(new int[] { 50, 50, 25, 22 });
    mRenderer.setLegendTextSize(25);
    // we show the grid
    mRenderer.setInScroll(true);
    mRenderer.setChartTitle(title);
    mRenderer.setChartTitleTextSize(30);

    //------------------------

    mRenderer.setClickEnabled(false);//the graph can't be clicked so that it can be refreshed as well as be zoomed in or out 
    mRenderer.setSelectableBuffer(10);

    //---------------------------

    String[] types = new String[]{ new String(TimeChart.TYPE), new String(ScatterChart.TYPE)};
    //return ChartFactory.getTimeChartView(context, dataset, mRenderer, "YYYY-MM-DD");
    return ChartFactory.getCombinedXYChartView(context, dataset, mRenderer, types);//return a graph depending on the above declarations, that will be used as a view in the previous activity
}

public void setData(boolean arePoints){//sets the temperatures and dates data that will be used on the graph
    Date[] dt = new Date[MainActivity.dates.size()]; 
    for (int k = 0; k< MainActivity.dates.size(); k++){
        GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar(MainActivity.dates.get(k).getYy(),
                MainActivity.dates.get(k).getMM()-1,MainActivity.dates.get(k).getDd(),
                MainActivity.dates.get(k).getHh(),MainActivity.dates.get(k).getMm(),
                MainActivity.dates.get(k).getSs());
        dt[k] = gc.getTime();
    }   
    if(!arePoints){
        TimeSeries series = new TimeSeries("Temperature");
        dataset.addSeries(series);
        int t = 0;
        for (t = 0; t < MainActivity.temps.size(); t++){
            series.add(dt[t] , MainActivity.temps.get(t));
        }
    }
    else{
        XYSeries pointSeries = new XYSeries("NotFromSensor");
        dataset.addSeries(pointSeries);
        int t = 0;
        for (t = 0; t < MainActivity.temps.size(); t++){
            pointSeries.add(dt[t].getTime(), MainActivity.temps.get(t));
        }
    }


}

public void setData(int i,boolean arePoints){//sets the temperatures and dates data that will be used on the graph
    Date[] dt = new Date[MainActivity.dates.size()]; 
    for (int k = 0; k< MainActivity.dates.size(); k++){
        GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar(MainActivity.dates.get(k).getYy(),
                MainActivity.dates.get(k).getMM()-1,MainActivity.dates.get(k).getDd(),
                MainActivity.dates.get(k).getHh(),MainActivity.dates.get(k).getMm(),
                MainActivity.dates.get(k).getSs());
        dt[k] = gc.getTime();
    }
    if(!arePoints){
        TimeSeries series = new TimeSeries("device "+DeviceFilterActivity.checkedDevices.get(i).getName());
        dataset.addSeries(series);
        int t = 0;
        for (t = 0; t < MainActivity.temps.size(); t++){
            series.add(dt[t] , MainActivity.temps.get(t));
        }
    }
    else{
        XYSeries pointSeries = new XYSeries("NotFromSensor");
        dataset.addSeries(pointSeries);
        int t = 0;
        for (t = 0; t < MainActivity.temps.size(); t++){
            pointSeries.add(dt[t].getTime() , MainActivity.temps.get(t));
        }
    }
}



public void clearDataset(){
    this.dataset.clear();
}
```

}

Obviously the chart shows the time in milliseconds. How can I use the X-Axis from the TimeChart and show the real dates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a solution to this problem. It's a custom library, something like an extention to the original AChartEngine. It includes a class named CombinedTimeChart. It is the exact same as the CombinedXYChart, but you can set the x-axis with the proper dates, without having to manually set its labels. I provide a link to get the library:

https://github.com/hdodenhof/achartengine

Credits to the creator for his good work. I tested it and works just great. The only thing you have to do is import the whole project into your workspace (if using Eclipse) and the import it as a library into your project:

- right click on your project name in Package Explorer.
- Properties
- Android
- Add...
- Choose the folder with the name of the imported project (achartengine-master)
- Apply
- OK

Now you are ready to use the library as you would have normally done with the original AChartEngine library. Remember to use the method `ChartFactory.getCombinedTimeChartView(context, dataset, renderer, type)` to get the chart with the choosen graphs.

I have seen many related questions around the forum with the answer "use CombinedXYChart with a LineChart and a ScatterChart", which is not a bad solution, but in my opinion the above is a better and easier way to create this kind of chart.

Hope it helps.